# Swift UserDefaults for Saving Custom Data Types: saved data disappears when I re-run the app and add a new data

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am making two-screen app that show the weight changing. On the first screen user inserts his weight. The current date and the inserted weight is changed in UserDefaults using class and Codable protocol. Then it is shown on the second screen in TableView.

The problem occurs when I re-run the app. I can load the data saved previously, but when I enter a new weight, it starts anew.

I suppose that the part with tableView.reloadData() is missing, but I don't know exactly where to put it.
[gif showing the app after re-opening it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GZL4.gif)

Here is my code (I shortened it).

```
// first screen
import UIKit

class WeightViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!

    var date = ""
    var cellArrayFirst = [CellModel]()
    let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("Weight.plist")



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        weightLabel.text! += getDate()

        weightTextField.delegate = self
        weightTextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }


    @IBAction func enterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let weight = weightTextField.text?.doubleValue {

            switch weight {
            case 0.0:
                weightTextField.text = ""
                weightTextField.placeholder = "Вес должен быть более 0.1 кг."
            case 0.1...200.00:
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
                cellArrayFirst.insert(CellModel(dateCell: date, weightCell: String(weight)), at: 0)
                self.saveItems()
                weightTextField.text = ""
            case 200.00...:
                weightTextField.text = ""
                weightTextField.placeholder = "Вес не должен быть более 200 кг."
            default:
                weightTextField.placeholder = "Укажите ваш вес"

            }
        }
    }

    func getDate() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        date = formatter.string(from: Date())

        return date
    }


    @IBAction func GoToDataButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
    }


    //MARK:- TextField Delegate Methods


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }


    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if string.isEmpty { return true }

        let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
        let replacementText = (currentText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        return replacementText.isValidDouble(maxDecimalPlaces: 2)

    }


    //MARK: - Model Manipulation Methods

    func saveItems () {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()

        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(cellArrayFirst)
            try data.write(to: dataFilePath!)
        } catch {
            print("Error encoding cellArrayFirst, \(error)")
        }
         // tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadItems() {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataFilePath!) {
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            do{
                cellArrayFirst = try decoder.decode([CellModel].self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding cellArrayFirst, \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// second screen
class StatisticsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var weightScreenData = WeightViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = 60.0
        tableView.reloadData()
        weightScreenData.loadItems()

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return weightScreenData.cellArrayFirst.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeightCell", for: indexPath) as! StatisticsCell

        cell.dateRecorded.text = weightScreenData.cellArrayFirst[indexPath.row].dateCell
        cell.weightRecorded.text = weightScreenData.cellArrayFirst[indexPath.row].weightCell

        return cell

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should do `reloadData()` after `loadItems()`. Off topic but move the load/save functionality out of the view controller into a separate struct/class, always better to separate responsibilities into separate types.

Comment: Thank you, @JoakimDanielson! I will try